# Find all the solutions for the equation

Tags: integration

So i'm trying to solve this problem from a functions equations but I wonder that if any solution exists with integral? If exist, how can I solve it? 
Here is the question:

$$4x+1 = (12x+3)e^{x^2 -2}$$

Comment: What do you mean "if any solution exists with integral"?

Comment: Either $4x+1=0$ or you can divide both parts by $(4x+1)\ne 0$. @colss

Comment: Can I solve it with integrate both left and right side?

Comment: Why would you want to solve it by integration?

Comment: If you do what Alexey suggests, you'll get either $x= -\frac14$, or else, $1= 3e^{x^2 -2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you want  $ x \in\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align}
(4x+1) & = (12x+3)e^{x^2 -2} \\
0 & = (12x+3)e^{x^2 -2}- (4x+1)\\ 
 & = (4x+1)(3e^{x^2 -2})- (4x+1) \\
& = (4x+1)(3e^{x^2 -2} - 1)
\end{align}

Now we let,

\begin{align}
4x+1 & = 0 \\
\therefore x &= -\frac{1}{4}.
\end{align}

With the other factor, we are going to set this equal to zero aswell, however, one might see that since the variable is in the exponent logarithims will be involved hence we might need the restriction $ x > 0 $. But, since the exponent is in $x^{2}$ we need not worry about getting solutions where $x < 0$. Okay, so now we let,

\begin{align}
3e^{x^2 -2} - 1 & = 0 \\
 e^{x^2 -2} & = \frac{1}{3} \\
e^{x^2 -2} & = e^{-\log{3}} \\
\therefore x^2 -2 & = -\log{3} \\
\implies x & = \pm \sqrt{2-\log{3}}.
\end{align}

Comment: Is the solution be with $ln(3)$ instead of log3?

Comment: @colss if you see log(x) without the base stated, you should assume until told otherwise that it is equal to ln(x) ... but yes here it is